# Pseudocode: Understanding constraints let ... in

Tags: constraints, static-code-analysis

I'm reading a book about constraint based static code analysis. (Name: principles of program analysis) In there I found this code snippet:

```
let f = fn x => x 7 
    g = fn y => y
    h = fn z => 3
in f g + f (g h)
```

It will be interpreted as:

```
f g   +   f (g h)
 |            |
 v            v
g 7          f h 
              |
              v
             h 7
```

I understand why `f g` will be `g 7`.

But why is `f (g h)` interpreted as `f h`? It should be  `g h 3`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In expression `f (g h)` first `g h` is interpreted as `h` (according to `g` definition) and than `f` is applied.